# Is there a way to get tab page by it's text

Tags: c#, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm changing text (renaming tabs) of tab pages in tab control and I want to access tab page by it's text. The problem is, that these pages are created in code and I couldn't access them by their names

```
var yourtabs = tabControlFEPages.Controls
                                .OfType<TabPage>()
                                .Where(tab => tab.Name.Equals(cmbFEEdytujKarteWybierzKarte.Text))
                                .ToList(); 

var index = tabControlFEPages.TabPages.IndexOf(yourtabs[0]).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(index);

foreach (TabPage tab in yourtabs)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tab.ToString());
}

tabControlFEPages.TabPages[index].Text = txtFEEdytujKarteNowaNazwa.Text;
```

Comment: You are looking at the controls of the current selected tab of the TabControl.  Try `tabControlFEPages.TabPages` to loop through the TabPage collection.

Comment: use `var yourtabs = tabControlFEPages.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().Where(tab => tab.Name.Equals(cmbFEEdytujKarteWybierzKarte.Text));` All tabpages with your text will be within `yourtabs`

Comment: I've pasted the code: `var yourtabs = tabControlFEPages.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().Where(tab => tab.Name.Equals(cmbFEEdytujKarteWybierzKarte.Text)); 
            var index = tabControlFEPages.TabPages.IndexOf(yourtabs).ToString();

            tabControlFEPages.TabPages[index].Text = txtFEEdytujKarteNowaNazwa.Text;`

Comment: add `.ToList()` behind my code sample and the `yourtabs`will behave like a Collection of `TabPage`. With this you can run through each tabpage with `foreach`loop and modify each tabpage with your text. Instead of `Name`use `Text`...misunderstood your question first.

Comment: Edit your question with your code.  Don't put it in comments.

Comment: Change `tab.ToString()` to `tab.Text`

Comment: THANKS A LOT! This worked, Here's my code:  `var yourtabs = tabControlFEPages.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().Where(tab => tab.Text.Equals(cmbFEEdytujKarteWybierzKarte.Text)).ToList(); 
            var index = tabControlFEPages.TabPages.IndexOf(yourtabs[0]);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFEEdytujKarteNowaNazwa.Text))
                tabControlFEPages.TabPages[index].Text = txtFEEdytujKarteNowaNazwa.Text.ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I wanted:

```
        var yourtabs = tabControlFEPages.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().Where(tab => 
        tab.Text.Equals(cmbFEEdytujKarteWybierzKarte.Text)).ToList(); 
        var index = tabControlFEPages.TabPages.IndexOf(yourtabs[0]);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFEEdytujKarteNowaNazwa.Text))
            tabControlFEPages.TabPages[index].Text = 
         txtFEEdytujKarteNowaNazwa.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: You don't have to do a ToString on a Text property.  It's already a string.